# are visual studio macros available in the Command Tool window?

Tags: visual-studio

[Macros for Build Commands and Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs.aspx) like $(SolutionDir) and $(ProjectDir) are available as [Arguments for External Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekbzk5f8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Are the same macros available to the [Shell Command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xca6kdd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the [Command Tool Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c338aexd.aspx)?

Right now I can resort to using an environment variable, and if I forget to set it before Visual Studio starts, I can remotely inject it. [Dynamically Add/Edit Environment Variables of Remote Process](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32131/Dynamically-Add-Edit-Environment-Variables-of-Remo)

> Tools.Shell /c tfpt.exe review %SOLUTIONDIR%

Is there a syntax for the Command Tool Window that will allow me to access the Build Macros?!

Did this syntax somehow escape the design considerations of the Visual Studio team?

> Tools.Shell /c tfpt.exe review $(SolutionDir)

Please send any syntax that is known to work, including version of Visual Studio.

If there's already a ticket open on [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/) for this, I'd accept that as an answer too.

Please no answers that suggest the many optional plugins for Visual Studio that host Powershell, Python or others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We took a look at the code and it doesn't seem that those macros are available today. I'll file a feature request.

Comment: Thanks for the update @scott-hanselman. 
In case anyone wants to vote for this, I opened a feature request on the Visual Studio UserVoice site. http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/4072115-add-the-path-macros-to-command-tool-window